How to Capture Requests with sb in SeleniumBase?
Description:
I'm encountering a challenge when using SeleniumBase. When using the sb instance, I can easily load cookies (e.g., sb.load_cookies(name="cookies.txt")), which is very convenient for maintaining session state. However, I have found that sb cannot directly capture network requests.
On the other hand, when using a driver instance, I can capture network requests, but it’s not straightforward to load cookies or maintain the session state. This creates difficulties when working with websites that require a logged-in state.
Problem:
The sb instance allows easy cookie loading but doesn't support direct request capture.
The driver instance supports request capture but lacks the convenience of loading cookies or maintaining a session state effectively.
this is my code:
from seleniumbase import SB

# Function to intercept and print specific requests
def print_specific_requests(driver):
    for request in driver.requests:        
        print(f"Request URL: {request.url}")
        print(f"Response Status Code: {request.response.status_code}")

def load_cookies_and_intercept():
    # Using `SB` with `wire=True` to enable request interception
    with SB(uc=True, wire=True) as sb:
        # Load cookies from file
        sb.open("https://xxx.io")
        sb.load_cookies(name="xxx.txt")

        # List of URLs to visit
        urls = [
            "https://xxxx",
            "https://yyyy",
        ]

        # Visit each URL and intercept the requests
        for url in urls:
            sb.open(url)
            print_specific_requests(sb.driver)

# Run the function to load cookies and intercept requests
load_cookies_and_intercept()

What I Tried: I used the sb instance in SeleniumBase to load cookies with sb.load_cookies(name="cookies.txt"), which works well for maintaining the session state across different pages. I then attempted to use driver to capture network requests with selenium-wire, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to load the cookies into the driver instance.
What I Expected: I expected to be able to use the sb instance to both load cookies and capture network requests in the same session. My goal was to capture specific requests after loading cookies and maintaining the session state.
What Actually Happened: While the sb instance allowed me to load cookies easily, it did not support capturing network requests directly. On the other hand, using driver with selenium-wire allowed me to capture requests but made it difficult to load cookies and maintain the session, leading to issues with logged-in pages.
